# While (PHP) listar os dados de 3 tabelas Mysql

Tags: php

Tenho um sistema do qual preciso trazer dentro de um while(), os resultados de 3 tabelas. Ex.:

**loja_operadores**

```
RAZAO_SOCIAL | CPNJ
Empresa1RS     000.111.222/0001-1
Empresa2RS     000.111.222/0001-2
Empresa3RS     000.111.222/0001-3
Empresa4RS     000.111.222/0001-4
```

**loja_masters**

```
RAZAO_SOCIAL | CPNJ
Empresa1RS      000.111.222/0001-1
```

**loja_gestores**

```
RAZAO_SOCIAL | CNPJ
Empresa1RS     000.111.222/0001-1
Empresa2RS     000.111.222/0001-2
```

Para isso, tentei dessa forma:

```
 public function comboEmpresasSystem($key)
    {
        $sql = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT LO.RazaoSocial AS RZLO, LO.CNPJ AS CNPJLO,
                                                   LG.RazaoSocial AS RZLG, LG.CNPJ AS CNPJLG, 
                                                   LM.RazaoSocial AS RZLM, LM.CNPJ AS CNPJLM     
                                            FROM loja_operadores LO
                                            INNER JOIN loja_gestores LG
                                            INNER JOIN loja_masters LM
                                            GROUP BY CNPJLO,CNPJLG,CNPJLM;");
    $visualizar = '';
    while($isfast = mysqli_fetch_object($sql))
    {
        $visualizar .= '<option>'.$isfast->CNPJLO.' - '.$isfast->RZLO.'</option>';
        $visualizar .= '<option>'.$isfast->CNPJLG.' - '.$isfast->RZLG.'</option>';
        $visualizar .= '<option>'.$isfast->CNPJLM.' - '.$isfast->RZLM.'</option>';
    }
    return $visualizar;
}
```

Porém o resultado não saiu como esperado, pois está me trazendo duplicidade das **tabela_masters** e **tabela_gestores**, já que a **tabela_operadores** tem mais dados cadastrados.

Tentei também com a query abaixo, mas deu os mesmos resultados:

```
SELECT LO.RazaoSocial AS RZLO, LO.CNPJ AS CNPJLO,
       LG.RazaoSocial AS RZLG, LG.CNPJ AS CNPJLG, 
       LM.RazaoSocial AS RZLM, LM.CNPJ AS CNPJLM     
FROM loja_operadores LO
INNER JOIN(
           SELECT * FROM loja_gestores GROUP BY CNPJ
           ) AS LG
INNER JOIN(
           SELECT * FROM loja_masters GROUP BY CNPJ
          ) AS LM;
```

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Está faltando a cláusula `ON` em seu `INNER JOIN`. Além disso, a estrutura no seu exemplo de dados está diferente da estrutura da query, o que dificulta o entendimento

Comment: Tem razão, Costa. Ajustei meu post e coloquei mais uma tentativa que não funcionou.

Comment: Pela sua tentativa, não sabe como usar o `INNER JOIN`, isso pode ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6448/91006

Comment: O problema é que as tabelas não têm ligações para incluir o ON, ou seja, não são relacionadas. A solução que achei foi criar uma query para cada tabela e cada uma delas receberem o próprio laço dentro do select HTML.

Comment: O que você quer de fato com esse select? Nem a pergunta e nem o código fazem muito sentido...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não consegui entender exatamente o que você está tentando retornar, mas se for os dados de todas as empresas como se fosse uma única lista, você pode usar o `UNION` ou `UNION ALL`, segue um exemplo:

```
SELECT
    RAZAO_SOCIAL 
    , CPNJ
FROM 
loja_operadores

UNION ALL

SELECT
    RAZAO_SOCIAL 
    , CPNJ
FROM 
loja_masters

UNION ALL

SELECT
    RAZAO_SOCIAL 
    , CPNJ
FROM 
loja_gestores
```

Comment: Obrigado, Jhonny